# Android ndk clang++.exe: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files

Tags: android, android-ndk

When I imported Webrtc's VAD to the Android project, I faced an error:
(Android Studio 3.4.1，NDK：19.2.5345600，gradle:3.4.1)
Could someone help me? thanks

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\xx.luo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build D:\workspace\Vad2\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a --target native-lib}
[1/1] Linking CXX shared library D:\workspace\Vad2\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a\libnative-lib.so
FAILED: D:/workspace/Vad2/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/arm64-v8a/libnative-lib.so
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\xx.luo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=aarch64-none-linux-android22 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/xx.luo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/xx.luo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o D:\workspace\Vad2\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a\libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/file_cut.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/period_format.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/simple_vad.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/cross_correlation.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/division_operations.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/downsample_fast.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/energy.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/get_scaling_square.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/min_max_operations.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_48khz.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_by_2_internal.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_fractional.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/spl_init.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/vector_scaling_operations.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_core.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_filterbank.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_gmm.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_sp.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/webrtc_vad.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/rtc_base/checks.cc.o  -llog D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/file_cut.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/main.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/period_format.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/simple_vad.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/common.h D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/file_cut.h D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/period_format.h D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/simple_vad.h D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/cross_correlation.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/division_operations.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/downsample_fast.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/energy.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/get_scaling_square.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/min_max_operations.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_48khz.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_by_2_internal.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_fractional.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/spl_init.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/vector_scaling_operations.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_core.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_filterbank.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_gmm.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_sp.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/webrtc_vad.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/rtc_base/checks.cc -latomic -lm && cd ."
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Edit:
I use gcc instead of clang++, and change different NDK Version, there are different errors:

```
 externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11"
                arguments "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc"
                abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
            }
        }
```

cmakelist:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
file(GLOB SRC_FILES src/*.c src/*.h thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/*/*.c thirdparty/webrtc/rtc_base/*.c*)
include_directories(thirdparty/webrtc) #thirdparty/include/webrtc
add_library( 
        native-lib
        SHARED
        native-lib.cpp
        ${SRC_FILES}
        )
find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib
        log)
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib
        ${log-lib}
        ${SRC_FILES})
```

when I use NDK 19:

```
Error configuring CMake server (C:\Users\xx.luo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin).
CMake Error at C:/Users/xx.luo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:169 (message):
  GCC is no longer supported.  See
  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/ClangMigration.md.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/xx.luo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:94 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt
```

when I use NDK 18b:

```
Error configuring CMake server (C:\Users\xx.luo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin).
CMake Error at D:/android-ndk-r18b/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:185 (message):
  GCC is no longer supported.  See
  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/ClangMigration.md.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/xx.luo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:94 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

when I use NDK 17c:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\xx.luo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build D:\workspace\Vad2\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a --target native-lib}
[1/1] Linking CXX shared library D:\workspace\Vad2\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a\libnative-lib.so
FAILED: D:/workspace/Vad2/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/arm64-v8a/libnative-lib.so
cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\android-ndk-r17c\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\aarch64-linux-android-g++.exe --sysroot=D:/android-ndk-r17c/sysroot -fPIC -isystem D:/android-ndk-r17c/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=22 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=c++11 -fno-strict-aliasing -std=c++11 -O0  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a --sysroot D:/android-ndk-r17c/platforms/android-22/arch-arm64 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -LD:/android-ndk-r17c/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o D:\workspace\Vad2\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a\libnative-lib.so @CMakeFiles/native-lib.rsp  && cd ."
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/file_cut.c:5:20: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
#include <stdlib.h>
compilation terminated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/main.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
#include <stdio.h>
.............
compilation terminated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/rtc_base/checks.cc:14:19: fatal error: cstdarg: No such file or directory
#include <cstdarg>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Edit:After I remove src/*.h: file(GLOB SRC_FILES src/*.c thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/*/*.c thirdparty/webrtc/rtc_base/*.c*)

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\xx.luo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build D:\workspace\Vad2\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a --target native-lib}
[1/1] Linking CXX shared library D:\workspace\Vad2\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a\libnative-lib.so
FAILED: D:/workspace/Vad2/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/arm64-v8a/libnative-lib.so 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\xx.luo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=aarch64-none-linux-android22 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/xx.luo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/xx.luo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o D:\workspace\Vad2\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a\libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/file_cut.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/period_format.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/simple_vad.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/cross_correlation.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/division_operations.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/downsample_fast.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/energy.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/get_scaling_square.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/min_max_operations.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_48khz.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_by_2_internal.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_fractional.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/spl_init.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/vector_scaling_operations.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_core.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_filterbank.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_gmm.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_sp.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/webrtc_vad.c.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/thirdparty/webrtc/rtc_base/checks.cc.o  -llog D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/file_cut.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/main.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/period_format.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/simple_vad.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/cross_correlation.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/division_operations.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/downsample_fast.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/energy.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/get_scaling_square.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/min_max_operations.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_48khz.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_by_2_internal.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_fractional.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/spl_init.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/vector_scaling_operations.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_core.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_filterbank.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_gmm.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_sp.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/webrtc_vad.c D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/rtc_base/checks.cc -latomic -lm && cd ."
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/file_cut.c:45:47: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
                 cut->output_filename_prefix, CAL_FRAME_BY_FRAME(cut->cut_begin_frame),
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/common.h:38:35: note: expanded from macro 'CAL_FRAME_BY_FRAME'
#define CAL_FRAME_BY_FRAME(frame) (MULTI * frame * 10)
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/file_cut.c:46:18: warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
                 CAL_FRAME_BY_FRAME(last_frame) - 1, cut->is_contain_active ? "A" : "I");
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/common.h:38:35: note: expanded from macro 'CAL_FRAME_BY_FRAME'
#define CAL_FRAME_BY_FRAME(frame) (MULTI * frame * 10)
                                  ^
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/file_cut.c:95:22: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'struct cut_info *' with an rvalue of type 'void *'
    struct cut_info *cut = calloc(1, sizeof(struct cut_info));
                     ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/main.c:2:10: fatal error: 'common_audio/vad/include/webrtc_vad.h' file not found
#include <common_audio/vad/include/webrtc_vad.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
In file included from D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/period_format.c:12:
In file included from D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/period_format.h:9:
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/simple_vad.h:12:10: fatal error: 'common_audio/vad/include/webrtc_vad.h' file not found
#include <common_audio/vad/include/webrtc_vad.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
In file included from D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/simple_vad.c:5:
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/src/simple_vad.h:12:10: fatal error: 'common_audio/vad/include/webrtc_vad.h' file not found
#include <common_audio/vad/include/webrtc_vad.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/cross_correlation.c:11:10: fatal error: 'common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h' file not found
#include "common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/division_operations.c:24:10: fatal error: 'common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h' file not found
#include "common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/downsample_fast.c:11:10: fatal error: 'common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h' file not found
#include "common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/energy.c:18:10: fatal error: 'common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h' file not found
#include "common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/get_scaling_square.c:18:10: fatal error: 'common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h' file not found
#include "common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/min_max_operations.c:29:10: fatal error: 'rtc_base/checks.h' file not found
#include "rtc_base/checks.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_48khz.c:19:10: fatal error: 'common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h' file not found
#include "common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_by_2_internal.c:17:10: fatal error: 'common_audio/signal_processing/resample_by_2_internal.h' file not found
#include "common_audio/signal_processing/resample_by_2_internal.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_fractional.c:18:10: fatal error: 'common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h' file not found
#include "common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/spl_init.c:17:10: fatal error: 'common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h' file not found
#include "common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/vector_scaling_operations.c:23:10: fatal error: 'common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h' file not found
#include "common_audio/signal_processing/include/signal_processing_library.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_core.c:11:10: fatal error: 'common_audio/vad/vad_core.h' file not found
#include "common_audio/vad/vad_core.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_filterbank.c:11:10: fatal error: 'common_audio/vad/vad_filterbank.h' file not found
#include "common_audio/vad/vad_filterbank.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_gmm.c:11:10: fatal error: 'common_audio/vad/vad_gmm.h' file not found
#include "common_audio/vad/vad_gmm.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_sp.c:11:10: fatal error: 'common_audio/vad/vad_sp.h' file not found
#include "common_audio/vad/vad_sp.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/common_audio/vad/webrtc_vad.c:11:10: fatal error: 'common_audio/vad/include/webrtc_vad.h' file not found
#include "common_audio/vad/include/webrtc_vad.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
D:/workspace/Vad2/app/src/main/cpp/thirdparty/webrtc/rtc_base/checks.cc:18:10: fatal error: 'typedefs.h' file not found
#include "typedefs.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Probably you are using a newer version of NDK to build older NDK project, try to figure out the proper NDK version may help.

Comment: So how to switch Ndk version？I cant find the way in AS.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52907340/8034839

Comment: let me see, Thanks a lot!

Comment: However I swiched NDK 13 and 16,same error.

Comment: try to use gcc instead of clang, this is because many older NDK project compiler configurations are based on gcc, but the later NDK use clang as default.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54821767/8034839

Comment: I use gcc and change different NDK version, there are still some new errors.

Comment: I am not sure I am pointing you in the right direction, but on seeing your edited question you are using cmake 3.10, i would try cmake 3.6 with NDK16 or 17 to see how it goes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files \[C error\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43525486/cannot-specify-o-when-generating-multiple-output-files-c-error)

Comment: No, it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
file(GLOB SRC_FILES ... src/*.h ...)
```

Stop trying to compile your headers.

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib
        ${log-lib}
        ${SRC_FILES})
```

The last line is wrong. Stop trying to link your source files.

Comment: after I remove the src/*.h and refresh project,there are some other errors:fatal error: 'typedefs.h' file not found
#include "typedefs.h",fatal error: 'common_audio/vad/vad_sp.h' file not found
#include "common_audio/vad/vad_sp.h" .....

Comment: That's a different problem. Your CMakeLists.txt is still wrong. You should look up an example of a CMakeLists.txt and go from there.